# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'array'

Tags: java, mysql, android-studio, array

lguien sabe por qué tengo este error? el año pasado tenía esta app funcionando bien y ahora me sale eso.

Les agradezco cualquier aporte
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es que en la línea 29, pues te falta el `=` donde defines tu array $temp Y la próxima vez por favor coloca el código como texto y no como imágen ya que sería mucho más difíçil (por no imposible) de ejecutar si alguien necesita probar el código.

Comment: Lo siento, es la primera vez que uso esto, hago lo que dices pero me sale este error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on bool in D:\xampp\htdocs\consultar.php:21 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\consultar.php on line 21

Comment: A lo mejor no es necesario que declares de nuevo el arreglo ya lo tienes declarado en la linea 26 y luego vuelves a declarar el arreglo en la linea 29 igual a lo mejor lo único que tienes que hacer es escribir $temp = Array();  <-- sin espacio entre el elemento Array y su parentesis.  Saludos

Comment: Bienvenido por favor agrega el código como texto no como imagen ya que algunos miembros de la comunidad no pueden ver la imagen.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que sea por esto `$temp = Array ();`   elimina el espacio entre el elemento Array y su parentesis `$temp = Array();` la otra posibilidad sea que ya tienes declarado un arreglo en la linea 26.  Saludos